# Filter and Merge inner table data

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am currently learning SQL.

Say I am having a table A with data (lets assume auto-increment field as primary key)

```
ID  FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4  FIELD5
1   1       null    null    null    null
1   null    2       null    4       null
1   null    null    3       null    null
1   null    null    null    null    5
```

Since the IDs are the same but the values are spread in various records. Is it possible to fetch a record using SQL say

```
ID  FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4  FIELD5
1   1       2       3       4       5
```

Please correct me if I am wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an aggregate function with a GROUP BY to get the result:

```
select id, 
  max(field1) as field1, 
  max(field2) as field2, 
  max(field3) as field3, 
  max(field4) as field4, 
  max(field5) as field5
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/968e1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Select Id, MAX(ISNULL(FIELD1, 0)), MAX(ISNULL(FIELD2, 0)), MAX(ISNULL(FIELD3, 0)), MAX(ISNULL(FIELD4, 0)), MAX(ISNULL(FIELD5, 0)) From tableA Group By Id

Comment: ISNULL is SQL Server syntax.  The Oracle equivalent would be NVL().  But it's unnecessary anyway, and perhaps undesirable.